# How to build a report with groups using C# and HTML? ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, html

I have data in this format

```
Reference |  QTY  | Units |  Boxes  |  Localization | Ticket
  M1000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP       |  7001
  M1000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP       |  7002
  M1000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP1      |  7003
  M1000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP1      |  7004
  M2000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP2      |  7006
  M2000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP2      |  7008
```

I would like it to appear like this

```
  Reference |  QTY  | Units |  Boxes  |  Localization | Ticket
    M1000   |  100  |  10   |    10   |     .MP       |  7001
            |       |       |         |               |  7002
            |       |       |         |     .MP1      |  7003
            |       |       |         |               |  7004
    M2000   |  300  |  20   |    15   |     .MP2      |  7006
            |       |       |         |               |  7008
```

How can i achieve this using HTML and C#?

Also I am using Dapper to retrieve this data and populate an object

I tried using Group By from LINQ and it works

```
   var result = supplies
                .GroupBy(la => new { la.Reference, la.Qty, la.Units , la.Boxes  });
```

now i just need how to add group inside group for Localization

References > Localization > tickets

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can achieve this by using group data and then operations like ‘sum’, ‘distinct’ and ‘select’. Try to see this way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby

Comment: thanks this helped me get closer to the expected result, i updated the post